# maintaining sessions in jsf and java beans

Tags: java, jsf

i am new to JSF and beans and i have a situation where i need to fetch some data from DB(oracle) and display on console. my first bean will read the data from JSF and call the appropriate method in the second bean and the list with data will be sent back to the bean. based on the data again one more method in the second bean will be called for additional data. finally the data will be published to the user. my second bean will be responsible for DB connections. here is my code.
first bean,

```
 String ban = null,ban1 = null;
 masterlist = (ArrayList<ThreadDTO>) getMbd().getBanOrCtn(dbean);
 if (masterlist.isEmpty()) {
     setSuccess(2);
     return;
    } else {
    Iterator<ThreadDTO> itr = masterlist.iterator();
       while (itr.hasNext()) {
       ThreadDTO dto = (ThreadDTO) itr.next();
       ban1 = dto.getWireless_ban();
       if (ban1 != null) {
       ban = ban1;
       break;
       }
     }

    ctnThreadList = (ArrayList<ThreadDTO>) getMbd().getThreads(dbean);
    dbean.setSearchby("wireless_ban");
    dbean.setSearchValue(ban);
    banThreadList = (ArrayList<ThreadDTO>) getMbd().getThreads(dbean);
    masterlist.clear();
    masterlist = (ArrayList<ThreadDTO>) getMbd().removeDuplicates(    ctnThreadList, banThreadList);
    setResultlist((ArrayList<ThreadDTO>) getMbd().getApis(masterlist));

    }
```

Second Bean is,

```
public ArrayList<ThreadDTO> getBanOrCtn(SearchDetailsDTO db) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<ThreadDTO> threadlist1 = new ArrayList<>();

   //query here

    try {
    connection = getConnections(timeZone);//getting connection
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(banQuery);

        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            System.out.println("empty resultset");
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            connection.close();

        } else {               
                while (rs.next()) {
                ThreadDTO thread = new ThreadDTO();

                //code to set the values

                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        addErrorMessage(sql.getMessage());
    }
    return threadlist;
}
```

this may not be a good coding practice, however this is working fine for single user but my requirement is to be accessed by multiple users. can any one please tell me how can i achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain data under scoped session between two beans, I would recommend you to inject managed beans. You can do that by using @ManagedProperty to annotate a bean in a different one. Then you can easily access methods of this bean. Here you can find more, as well as an example. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply David. I am still getting ExhaustedResultSet and Closed ResultSet error. but this has to be differentiated by session right? pls let me know how to over come this error.